# How to start Unity Editor on Linux?

Tags: linux, unity-game-engine

I downloaded the latest version of Unity platform-agnostic self-extracting installation script and successfully installed it:

```
$ sudo sh ./unity-editor-installer-5.4.0p1+20160810.sh 
Installer for Unity 5.4.0p1

Press Enter to begin extracting to ./unity-editor-5.4.0p1

Unpacking Unity 5.4.0p1 ...
Extraction complete. Run ./unity-editor-5.4.0p1/Editor/Unity to begin
```

Then I tried to run the Editor:

```
$ ./unity-editor-5.4.0p1/Editor/Unity
```

These two windows appear immediately when the command above is run:

[image]

and nothing more happened for the whole night. No error messages, no console output, no log files and no syslog entries. `top` utility shows that Unity process utilizes one core for 100% of it's CPU time.

I run OpenSUSE 13.2 with up-to-date nVidia graphics drivers. My system also matches all dependencies and requirements listed [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/), and I didn't see any other instructions except "run the installation script, then run the editor". Unity works OK on Windows with the same hardware.

So my questions are:

1. How (if possible) to run Unity Editor on non-Ubuntu distributions?
2. Where can I find error messages (if any) which might clarify the reasons of the issue?

Comment: As far as I know, unity only works properly on Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't know if you've seen this thread yet, but there might be something to help out, over here: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-install-unity-3d-under-opensuse.414359/

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm getting the same on Ubuntu 12.04 with kernel 3.13.0-106-generic. The laptop is a Dell XPS 17 (L702x with an NVidia GT550m GPU, 16gb RAM). Unity 5.6.0xb3Linux.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a common linux bug.

I can't make any assurances but what worked for me (and what seems to be the most suggested fix on the unity forums) is to do two things:

- update or install NPM
- create the directory "~/.local/share/unity3d/Packages"

If your npm is up to date, the directory thing seems to be the big to-do (it worked like crackers for me).

If you've got both...well, at least you get the joy of adventure trying to figure out what else could be going against you.